# Ignore folders in htaccess

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm making a webapp using AngularJS. For routing, I used a `htaccess` rewrite rule to allow direct access to routing pages (for example going directly to /settings). However there is one folder I would like to exclude from this rule, so I can check if a file exists (now every URL returns 200). I've tried every combination of rewrite conditions and rules I could find, but no luck.

So far this is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(orders)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

I would appreciate any help

EDIT:
I would like to exclude all files and folders under `orders`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/orders [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]
```

`%{REQUEST_URI}` always starts with a `/` and because you aren't specifying something like `.*` at the beginning of the regex, you have to have the slash. I also added the `[NC]` flag so that a url like "/ORDerS" would be skipped as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response. however, I could not get this to work. Every url gets routed through angular.